# Pade approximation of vector or operator functions

Tags: matrix, series-expansion

`PadeApproximant` is a very useful function of MA that starts with a truncated Taylor series

$$f(x)\approx\sum_{k=0}^{l} c_k (x-x_0)^k,$$

and represents them in a rational form

$$f(x)\approx\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{m} a_i (x-x_0)^i}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}  b_j (x-x_0)^j}.$$

Thus, Padé approximantion: $c_k \rightarrow (a_i,b_j)$.

Recently, I faced a problem to perform such approximation for vector (or even operator) functions $\hat f(x)$. The requirement is, however, that there is a *common* denominator for all components:

$$\hat f(x)\approx\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{m} \hat a_i (x-x_0)^i}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}  b_j (x-x_0)^j}.$$

In other words, the $b_j$ are scalars. Because of this, the `PadeApproximate` function cannot be used. I know that such methods exist and used, for instance, to speed up computations of the matrix exponents. In fact, the whole section 8 in *Padé approximants* by Baker and Graves-Morris is devoted to this problem. However, the book is written in too formalized way that I cannot even figure out working formulas. I hope that someone here has an experience with this method.

The basic example in the documentation is

```
PadeApproximant[Exp[x], {x, 0, {2, 3}}]
```

Here the desired syntax is

```
MatrixPadeApproximant[MatrixExp[{{1,x},{x,x^2}}], {x, 0, {2, 3}}]
```

Thus, for matrix Padé approximantion: $\hat c_k \rightarrow (\hat a_i,b_j)$ is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in essence requesting a simultaneous Pade-like approximation.You probably realize that the degree bounds guaranteed by a Pade approximation cannot apply for simultaneous approximation (it would be an over-constrained problem).

One can obtain this type of approximation using a method that gives the polynomial analog to simultaneous rational approximation as done in the Wolfram Function Repository (WFR) item `ResourceFunction["SimultaneousRationalize"]`. This uses the "extended" form of lattice reduction that delivers both reduced matrix and conversion matrix. It also lives in the WFR, as `ResourceFunction["ExtendedLatticeReduce"]`

The polynomial analog to lattice reduction is known as the Popov form. The extended variant is also conveniently found in the WFR, as `ResourceFunction["PopovDecomposition"]`. (You are at this point no doubt asking yourself if the Wolfram Function Repository perhaps loves you. The answer is yes, it loves you very much.)

For a simple illustration of how to use this for the problem at hand, I show a simultaneous approximation example using the functions `exp(x)` and `sin(x)` both expanded to degree 9 at the origin.

```
n = 9;
mat = {{Normal[Series[Exp[x], {x, 0, n}]], 
   Normal[Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, n}]], 1}, {x^(n + 1), 0, 0}, {0, 
   x^(n + 1), 0}}

(* Out[295]= {{1 + x + x^2/2 + x^3/6 + x^4/24 + x^5/120 + x^6/720 + x^7/
   5040 + x^8/40320 + x^9/362880, 
  x - x^3/6 + x^5/120 - x^7/5040 + x^9/362880, 1}, {x^10, 0, 0}, {0, 
  x^10, 0}} *)
```

Find the Popov matrix decomposition.

```
{mult, red} = 
  Expand[ResourceFunction["PopovDecomposition"][mat]];
```

Check this result.

```
Expand[mult.mat - red]

(* Out[293]= {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}} *)
```

Now use it to obtain the rational approximations. Note that the polynomials are degree 6, which is as earlier noted worse than what could be obtained from separate Pade approximations.

```
rats = red[[1, 1 ;; 2]]/mult[[1, 1]]

(* Out[297]= {(-307257753600 - 237758976000 x - 90531302400 x^2 - 
    22295347200 x^3 - 3766694400 x^4 - 415860480 x^5 - 
    23950080 x^6)/(-307257753600 + 69498777600 x - 6401203200 x^2 + 
    566092800 x^3 + 87091200 x^4 - 54432000 x^5 + 
    6894720 x^6), (-307257753600 x + 69498777600 x^2 + 
    44808422400 x^3 - 11017036800 x^4 - 1406522880 x^5 + 
    430375680 x^6)/(-307257753600 + 69498777600 x - 6401203200 x^2 + 
    566092800 x^3 + 87091200 x^4 - 54432000 x^5 + 6894720 x^6)} *)
```

We do a numeric check that this result makes sense.

```
Table[rats - {Exp[x], Sin[x]}, {x, -1., 1., .1}]

(* Out[298]= {{2.49937*10^-8, -1.025*10^-6}, {9.30599*10^-9, \
-3.64533*10^-7}, {3.0613*10^-9, -1.14436*10^-7}, {8.60624*10^-10, \
-3.0673*10^-8}, {1.96938*10^-10, -6.68594*10^-9}, {3.40138*10^-11, \
-1.09896*10^-9}, {3.90687*10^-12, -1.20025*10^-10}, {2.35589*10^-13, \
-6.87128*10^-12}, {4.10783*10^-15, -1.2107*10^-13}, {-1.11022*10^-16, \
-1.249*10^-16}, {0., 
  0.}, {-2.22045*10^-16, -1.38778*10^-16}, {5.9952*10^-15, \
-1.28314*10^-13}, {3.5616*10^-13, -7.49828*10^-12}, {6.79035*10^-12, \
-1.34856*10^-10}, {6.78817*10^-11, -1.27139*10^-9}, {4.51343*10^-10, \
-7.96499*10^-9}, {2.26517*10^-9, -3.76308*10^-8}, {9.25418*10^-9, \
-1.44595*10^-7}, {3.23129*10^-8, -4.74433*10^-7}, {9.96934*10^-8, \
-1.37423*10^-6}} *)
```

I do not want to belabor how this works, but the idea is that the matrix identity we checked can be recast as approximations between polynomials up to order 10. A staightforward division with a common denominator then approximates the two functions in question.

We can package it as below. Caveat: I have not tested this heavily.

```
simultaneousPade[funcs_List, var_, n_Integer, pt_ : 0] := Module[
  {servec, lat, mult, red},
  servec = Append[Normal[Series[funcs, {var, pt, n}]], 1];
  lat = Join[{servec}, 
    var^(n + 1)*Most[IdentityMatrix[Length[servec]]]];
  {mult, red} = Expand[ResourceFunction["PopovDecomposition"][lat]];
  red[[1, 1 ;; -2]]/mult[[1, 1]]
  ]
```

Quick test:

```
sp = simultaneousPade[{Exp[x], Sin[x], Cos[x]}, x, 11, Pi/2];

Table[
 sp - {Exp[x], Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, Pi/2 - .3, Pi/2 + .3, .1}]

(* Out[308]= {{-2.78*10^-6, -7.94652*10^-7, 
  3.91928*10^-7}, {-6.9551*10^-6, -1.95789*10^-6, 
  1.0296*10^-6}, {-0.0000163332, -4.52353*10^-6, 
  2.53193*10^-6}, {-0.0000363064, -9.88266*10^-6, 
  5.87886*10^-6}, {-0.0000769114, -0.0000205553, 
  0.0000129788}, {-0.000156141, -0.0000409307, 
  0.000027402}, {-0.000305195, -0.0000783892, 0.000055594}} *)
```

Comment: Hi Daniel! This is so amazing that you programmed these polynomial decompositions. And the connection of polynomial algebra to the Pade approximation is so unexpected.  Let me check it out.

Comment: I've already made some tests, it's really what I was looking for. But I have a couple of questions: 1) The expansion coefficients need not be rational, right? I am probably confused here with the connection to extended lattice reduction. 2) I noticed that a vector of functions is expanded to a matrix and subsequently the decomposition is performed. Would the procedure for a matrix be any different, or to flatten the matrix is sufficient?

Comment: (1) Correct, no need to be rational. It might even work with floating point coeffs (I didn't try and do not remember whether or to what extent the `PopovDecomposition` supports them). The connection to lattice reduction (in case not clear) is only that this is the univariate polynomial analog to what `LatticeReduce` does for integer lattices.

Comment: (2) Offhand I think flattening the matrix is the only way to do it, at least if the denominator is to be common across all elements.

Comment: Hi Daniel, just a short question. Is there any way to impose the order of numerator and denominator. In my calculations I know that functions decay as 1/x, therefore, I would like to find [n,n+1] approximants. Do you think this would be possible?

Comment: I'm not sure whether an order can be imposed. There is a way to get more results though. Change the last line of my code to use a different row from the result. If memory serves, this is just a matter of changing the first indices e.g. to `red[[2, 1 ;; -2]]/mult[[2, 1]]`. So you have alternative results and choose the one you like best. It might be possible to exert influence by using something other than the Popov decomposition but offhand I cannot think of a "better" term ordering to influence the degree reduction.